# DatePicker, seleccionar día siguiente al actual en React

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

tengo un DatePicker para seleccionar fechas y agendar, pero no quiero que me mantenga seleccionado el día actual. Sino que seleccione a partir del día siguiente.

Código:

```
<FormGroup>
    <DatePicker
    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    locale={es}
    inline
    name="firstDate"
    minDate={new Date()}
    selected={this.state.firstDate}
    onChange={(e) => this.selectDate(e, 'firstDate')}
    className="form-control"/>
</FormGroup>
```

El componente DatePicker lo saco de acá:

```
class Booking extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             ...
             dateSelector: "1",
             initialDate: new Date(),
             firstDate: new Date(),
             secondDate: new Date(),
             thirdDate: new Date(),
             ...
         }
     }
 }
```

Gracias

Comment: Deberias adjuntar de donde estas sacando ese componente DatePicker

Comment: class Booking extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
...
dateSelector: "1",
initialDate: new Date(),
firstDate: new Date(),
secondDate: new Date(),
thirdDate: new Date(),
...

Comment: Mas bien modifica la pregunta porque aqui sale recortado

Comment: Listo, espero te sirva y puedas ayudarme.

Comment: En el codigo que añadiste a la pregunta todavia no sale nada del datepicker, por ejemplo podrias decirme que libreria estas usando para el datepicker, por ejemplo import Datepicker from '....' ahi ya podria darme una idea de que libreria estas usando

Comment: import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar moment para manejar las fechas, lo hace muy facil

Para instalarlo debes escribir esto en la consola

```
npm install moment --save
```

En el archivo donde tienes el componente agregas esto hasta arriba

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

Y modificas lo que pusiste en `minDate` por una funcion de moment

```
this.state = {
  ...
  dateSelector: "1",
  initialDate: new Date(),
  firstDate: moment().add(1, 'day').toDate(),
  secondDate: new Date(),
  thirdDate: new Date(),
  ...
}

<FormGroup>
    <DatePicker
    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    locale={es}
    inline
    name="firstDate"
    minDate={moment().add(1, 'day').toDate()}
    selected={this.state.firstDate}
    onChange={(e) => this.selectDate(e, 'firstDate')}
    className="form-control"/>
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: Sigue dejándolo seleccionado predeterminado. Y es lo que no quiero, porque igual escogerían ese día.

Comment: ah ok, es porque selected lo tienes igual, modifique la respuesta

Comment: ¡Agradecido! Me sirvió.

Comment: podrias marcar la respuesta como aceptada, para marcar que ya se resolvio